# Laravel Vue Components can only pass numbers?

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

In my UserMenu.vue i wrote:

```
export default {
        props: ['nameVal'],
        data () {
            return {
            }
        }
    }
```

and in the blade.php

```
<usermenu v-bind:name-val='{{ 111 }}'>
```

This works fine, but only if i use numbers :-( if i use for example {{ abc }} it will throw an error

> Use of undefined constant abc - assumed 'abc' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)

If I use {{ 'abc' }} instead nothing is passed. How can I pass non numerical values? Or what is the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you're trying to use `v-bind` for a string literal value.

What you want instead is

```html
<usermenu name-val="abc">
```

or if you insist on using blade markup

```html
<usermenu name-val="{{ 'abc' }}">
```

**Note:** There is no `v-bind` or `:` prefix on the attribute.

---

The problem is that using [`v-bind` expects an expression](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Attributes). When you have this in PHP...

```html
<usermenu v-bind:name-val="{{ 'abc' }}">
```

the resulting markup is...

```html
<usermenu v-bind:name-val="abc">
```

so Vue would be looking for an `abc` data property (or similar). If you must use `v-bind`, you need to create a string literal expression. For example

```html
<usermenu v-bind:name-val="'{{ 'abc' }}'">
<!-- or -->
<usermenu v-bind:name-val="`{{ 'abc' }}`">
```