# my component is not displaying-vuejs-laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js

tried to show component in my blade but it still not working.i used laravel 7

there is my vue

```
<template>
    <h3>Option Values</h3>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        name: "attribute-values",
        props: ['attributeid'],
    }
</script>
```

there is how i call it in my view

```
<div class="tab-pane" id="values">
          <attribute-values :attributeid="{{ $attribute->id }}"></attribute-values>
                </div>
```

i import it in js file

```
Vue.component('attribute-values', require('./components/AttributeValues.vue').default);
```

there is my package.json file

```
"devDependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
    "cross-env": "^7.0",
    "jquery": "^3.2",
    "laravel-mix": "^5.0.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.19",
    "popper.js": "^1.12",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^2.3.1",
    "sass": "^1.20.1",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "vue": "^2.5.17",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10"
},
"dependencies": {
    "vue-swal": "^0.1.0",
    "vue-js-modal": "^1.3.26"
}
```

what should i do .thank you in advance.
i run npm run dev and npm run watch many times. my file js is generated in public folder so there is no problem. but component still not showed up.

Comment: Please replace the images with the actual code

Comment: Also, please make sure you're running `npm run dev`

Comment: run it multiple times. still no change

Comment: In your blade view, make sure the parent div has an ID of `app`

Comment: Change `:attributeid` to just `attributeid` ie, remove the `:` prefix. You're not binding any data value there so don't use `v-bind`. You probably have an error in your browser console about this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel Vue Components can only pass numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60628407/laravel-vue-components-can-only-pass-numbers)

Comment: [Vue.js devtools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/nhdogjmejiglipccpnnnanhbledajbpd) browser plugins help with debugging.

Comment: yess i have id=app in parent div.tried also to use devtools but no error is showing

Comment: thank you phil for your response but it still not working. i delete :. but still not showing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved it. all what i did is i separate div id=app from my content.because tags don't match with vue.and i add vue.use(component) like below in my js file:

```
 import AttributeValues from './components/AttributeValues.vue'
    Vue.use(AttributeValues);
    
    Vue.component('attribute-values', require('./components/AttributeValues.vue').default, {
        name: 'attribute-values'
    });
```

hope that it solve someone's problem.